# Customizing JupyterLab Launcher

Tags: jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I'd like to add some custom content in my JupyterLab Launcher. This is the first page that new users see and I want to tell them about specifics of this environment and link to stuff. Kind of like this:

[image: Illustration with new section in launcher]

The [Launcher's code](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/tree/v1.1.4/packages/launcher) is simple, and I can modify it to my liking. But I have trouble with applying the changes.

This is a JupyterHub environment ([zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s](https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/)) with a custom singleuser image that is derived from [`jupyter/datascience-notebook`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook).

The launcher is not a normal labextension. Can I make an extension to replace it anyway? Or should I try to patch in my changes somewhere? Where? I can't even find the Launcher's code inside the image.

Comment: I ended up writing a TSX snippet and injecting it into the minified `vendors~main.xxx.js` file via `sed`. Next question: How do I get this past a code review? _crying_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed a similar solution and found the answer at the [elyra-ai/elyra](https://github.com/elyra-ai/elyra) project!

What you need to do is to extend the main Launcher as it is done on Elyra's theme pacakge - [packages/theme/src/launcher.tsx](https://github.com/elyra-ai/elyra/blob/dc7c0e43afab0ba3e19311982cc019a7dd2c91cd/packages/theme/src/launcher.tsx)  and then and the bottom of that file add your HTML fixes, should be looking something like this (launcher.tsx):

```js
...
     return (
      <div className="jp-Launcher-body">
        <div className="jp-Launcher-content">
          <div className="jp-Launcher-cwd">
            <h3>Welcome! Here are few tips: ....</h3>
          </div>
          {categories}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
...
```

Keep in mind that there is an additional setup in order for this to work. Mainly - you need to disable the main jupyter launcher. In a command line it is simple:

```sh
jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/launcher-extension
```

However, you most likelly need to install this as a JupyterLab extension, so you have to disable the extension via page settings - this is what [Elyra did](https://github.com/elyra-ai/elyra/blob/dc7c0e43afab0ba3e19311982cc019a7dd2c91cd/etc/config/settings/page_config.json):

```json
{
  "disabledExtensions": ["@jupyterlab/launcher-extension"]
}
```

The last part is something where you can make a lot of tiny mistakes (forget to add it to setup.py data files, forget it on MANIFEST.in and etc). So I recommend to follow the [original commit](https://github.com/elyra-ai/elyra/commit/98703b4bfcb80ff538585323d0d44b03ff23cfe7#diff-15189663b12ed0583113ad69dee29082a83dfbaff37aeeba7df361b91df5f47a)

Good luck, and big thanks to Elyra team!